# Having trouble printing my .txt file into Rows and Columns, only the first row prints

Tags: c

Hey everyone I am new here and thought I would ask for some advice. I have my code setup to read my Maze.txt file in and have the rows and columns be scanned in and printed out instead of just reading the text file. Instead I am only getting the very first row to read in and no columns in. It looks like it is only the first line above the s, but all across and it won't go to the newline. I was wondering if I made a simple mistake or do I need to re allocate more memory to Cols?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LENGTH 100


typedef struct maze{
    struct maze *next;
    char *Rows;
    char *Cols;
    short Starts;
    short Goals;
} MAZE;

MAZE *first = NULL;
MAZE *last = NULL;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    FILE *fp;
    char line[LENGTH],Rows[LENGTH], Cols[LENGTH];
    MAZE *PM;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");// read mode

    if( fp == NULL )
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets (line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {

        // Check for errors
        if (line[0] == '\0') {
            printf ("Line too short\n");
            return -1;
        }

        if (line[strlen (line)-1] != '\n') {
            printf ("Line starting with '%s' is too long\n", Rows);
            return -1;
        }

        Rows[strlen (Rows)+1] = '\0';

        if (sscanf (line, "%s %s", Rows, Cols) != 1)
        {
            printf ("Line '%s' didn't scan properly\n", line);
            return -1;
        }

        PM = malloc (sizeof (MAZE));
        if (PM == NULL) {
            printf ("Ran out of memory\n");
            return -1;
        }

        PM->Rows = strdup (Rows);
        PM->Cols = strdup (Cols);
        PM->next = NULL;
        if (first != NULL) {
            last->next = PM;
            last = PM;
        } else {
            first = PM;
            last = PM;
        }
        fclose(fp);

        PM = first;
        while(PM != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n%s",PM->Rows,PM->Cols);
            PM = PM->next;

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Also my Maze.txt file looks like this.

```
######################################################################## 
#s  # #  #                                                             # 
# # #    ############ #################### #################### ##### ## 
# # # ## #                                         #  ########      #  # 
# # # #  #################### #################### ##          ####### # 
# # # ## #                                         ###########    #  # # 
# # # #  # #########################################           #####   # 
#     ##                                           # ######### #  ###### 
# # # #  # #################### ################ ### #                 # 
# # # ## #   #############                  #      # ## ################ 
# # # #  #                 ######################  #                   # 
# # # ## # ###################  #   #   #     #    ######  ########### # 
# # #    #   #############        #   #    #       #       #   #       # 
# # # #  #                 ####################    ######### # # ## ## # 
# #   ## #          #############                          # # # ## ## # 
# # # ## # #############                           ####### # # #       # 
# # # ## #                       ####################      # # # ## ## # 
# ### ## #  ####################                   ####### # # # ## ## # 
#     #  #                                               #     #      g# 
########################################################################
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the following errors:

1. You have a call to `fclose` in the `while` loop. That means, after the first line is read, the file gets closed. Hence, you end up reading only one line.
2. You also have the code to print the lines in the `while` loop. It so happens that the the code in the `while` loop gets executed only once. Hence, you get only one line in the output.

You need to move the call to `fclose` and the code to print the lines outside the `while` loop.

And some more..

I don't understand what you intended to do with the line:

```
    Rows[strlen (Rows)+1] = '\0';
```

As the code stands now, that would result in undefined behavior since `Rows`, which evaluates to a pointer to the first element of the array is uninitialized.

The line

```
  if (sscanf (line, "%s %s", Rows, Cols) != 1)
```

is not well thought out. If you expect to find exactly one item in `line`, use:

```
  if (sscanf (line, "%s %s", Rows) != 1)
```

If you expect to find exactly two items in `line`, use:

```
  if (sscanf (line, "%s %s", Rows, Cols) != 2) // 2, not 1
```

I am not able to suggest any fixes for these since I don't know what you are hoping to accomplish with them.

**Disclaimer** There maybe other errors in the code.

Comment: That made a lot of sense, after I did that it is telling me my line starting with a '#' is too long. So I am guessing I need to change the allocation to perfectly match my first line. Which should be 72 characters long. Is my memory allocation for the whole maze the problem? Would I instead need to allocate memory for the Rows and Cols separate?

Comment: @R Sahu, I am trying to get everything in that text file (Rows and Columns) to be printed out exactly how it appears in the text file. However doing it without calling a printf statement and instead displaying it line by line.

Comment: @Mags, it seems to me that you are unclear how to represent the data for the maze. I think that you need just one object of type `Maze` but then you have defined `Maze` to be a linked list. It's unclear to me how you are intending to capture the data.

Comment: @R Sahu, I am really new to C. I picked up a C programming book coming from some not well taught Java classes. You are right in the fact I am unclear on some things. What I am trying to do is to take my text file and read it into the structs memory then have that memory called back and print out the maze lines.

Comment: @Mags, It seems to me that you are trying to run before learning to walk. I would suggest trying something less complex first.